# How to read and set private fields without a performance hit in c#?

Tags: c#, performance, reflection

RavenDB can serialize all public, private and protected properties on any given C# object, even without any serialization attributes.

I know that this can be done with reflection, but that would have some performance issues. Are there other more efficient ways to achieve this?

To use the built-in serialization in .NET requires annotations or implementing some serialization interfaces, whereas RavenDB can serialize any given object to and from JSON.

I'm more interested in technology it uses and not RavenDB in specific.

Comment: Don't. Just don't. They are private for a reason.

Comment: What is the goal you're trying to achieve? Those variables are private for a reason; why are you trying to break the design?

Comment: Im interested in how this could be done, to understand how RavenDB and other solutions work.

Comment: There is no magic that RavenDB does - it utilizes the built in serialization capabilities of the platform (which already handles serializing public, private and protected properties, unless instructed otherwise).

Comment: @Oded Won't the objects have to be annotated with [Serializable] then?

Comment: @Jørgen - It depends on the serializer you use. And it is still not magic, but built into the framework.

Comment: @Jørgen The only one who cares about `[Serializable]` is the built in `BinaryFormatter` class. It's just a normal serializer which gets and sets fields through standard APIs. There is no reason why another serializer would need the same attributes.

Answer (score 1):

If setting properties through reflection is too slow, you can generate dynamic methods that set them at runtime. This can be done using `Relection.Emit` or by creating an compiling an `Expression<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

Look to NHibernate for inspiration - besides other alternatives it also gives you the opportunity to express which properties to persist using interfaces. Under the hood wrapper objects implementing the interfaces does change handling.

See for instance [NHibernate Reflection Optimizer - what does it do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935376/nhibernate-reflection-optimizer-what-does-it-do)